# How can I set the properties of React Player depending on the active slide of bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-carousel

```js
<Carousel fade interval={5000} variant="dark" className='gallery-width pb-5'>
                        <Carousel.Item  className="d-flex justify-content-center" >
                            <ReactPlayer controls={false} playing={true} loop={true} muted={true} url={dog1} pip={false} />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <ReactPlayer controls={false} playing={true} loop={true} muted={true} url={dog2} />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                             <ReactPlayer controls={false} playing={true} loop={true} muted={true} url={dog3} />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <ReactPlayer controls={false} playing={true} loop={true} muted={true} url={dog4} />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <ReactPlayer controls={false} playing={true} loop={true} muted={true} url={dog5} />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                             <ReactPlayer controls={false} playing={true} loop={true} muted={true} url={dog6} />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                             <ReactPlayer controls={false} playing={true} loop={true} muted={true} url={dog7} />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                    </Carousel>
```

How can I find out which Caoursel item is currently active and then set ONLY that carousel item to be unmuted?